# Java generics: How to wrap/extend Android Activity test case?

Tags: java, android, generics

I am trying to extend ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 as follows:

```
public abstract class FooActivityTestCase<T extends Activity>
  extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Activity> {

  public FooActivityTestCase(String pckg, Class<Activity> activityClass)
  {
    super(pckg, activityClass);
  }

  public void foo(){ ... }
}
```

I try to extend `FooActivityTestCase` like this:

```
public class SpecificFooTestCase
  extends FooActivityTestCase<MyActivity> {
  public SpecificFooTestCase() {
    super("foo.bar", MyActivity.class);  // error on this line
  }
}
```

Eclipse gives me the following error in the constructor:

```
The constructor FooActivityTestCase<MyActivity>(String, Class<MyActivity>) is undefined
```

I am pretty sure that the issue is with how I am using generics.  When `SpecificFooTestCase` extends `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` I don't get any errors.  Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong?

---

Kublai Khan's and Michael Myers' suggestions work in conjunction.  After I changed `FooActivityTestCase` to extend `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T>` and `Class<Activity>` to `Class<T>` in the constructor, the classes compile without errors.  This is the resulting class (SpecificFooTestCase hasn't changed):

```
public abstract class FooActivityTestCase<T extends Activity>
  extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T> {

  public FooActivityTestCase(String pckg, Class<T> activityClass)
  {
    super(pckg, activityClass);
  }

  public void foo(){ ... }
}
```

Comment: Can you replace the Class<Activity> parameter with Class<T>? (Without having Android, I'm just guessing.)

Comment: It looks like `FooActivityTestCase` should extend `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T>` rather than `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Activity>` specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the super constructor like this:

```
//Only accepts classes that are Activity or extend Activity
 public FooActivityTestCase(String pckg, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass)
      {
        super(pckg, activityClass);
      }
```

The thing is that for generics arguments, the generic type ***must always be exactly the same generic type***, if you want to be able to pass something in the inheritance tree you need to use the wildcard `? and extends`, this way you can pass it any generic type that extends that class.

Comment: This is very close.  However, it looks like I have to cast activityClass to Class<Activity> before this will compile.

Comment: Having Class<? extends Activity> is probably a better way of doing it.

Answer (score -2):

This is how I do Android unit testing:

```
public class MyInstrumentationTestRunner extends InstrumentationTestRunner 
{
    @Override
    public TestSuite getAllTests() 
    {
        InstrumentationTestSuite suite = new InstrumentationTestSuite(this);
        suite.addTestSuite(MyTestClass.class);
        return suite;
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getLoader() 
    {
        return MyInstrumentationTestRunner.class.getClassLoader();
    }
}
```

And define your test classes as such:

```
public class myTestClass extends
    ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Home> 
{
    Context _context;

    public MyTestClass() 
    {
        super("com.MyClassToTest", Home.class);
    }

    public void testfunction() 
    {
        myFunction(_context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception 
    {
        super.setUp();
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        _context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```